# What is a better set of settings to use than text to compare xml files using Collaborator's DiffMerge?

Tags: diffmerge, code-collaborator

Collaborator uses DiffMerge to compare files.  It provides a means to add rulesets.  There is nothing provided for XML files.  I'd like to be able to compare without including the comments.  I can get sections on the same line to behave with `\<!--.*--\>`

Multiline comments are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Better, but not close to perfect.  XML really needs ...

In any case, creating a Custom Context for the multi-line comments does exclude those comments from the testing of "this changed".

```
    Ruleset: XML Files
    Suffixes: xml runsettings config
    Line Match Handling: [0x00000010]
        Ignore/Strip EOLs: true
        Ignore/Fold Case: true
        Strip Whitespace: true
            Also Treat TABs as Whitespace: true
    Default Context Guidelines: [0x0000001a]
        Classify Differences as Important: true
            EOL differences are important: N/A
            Case differences are important: true
            Whitespace differences are important: false
                Treat TABs as Whitespace: true
    Custom Contexts: [1 contexts]
        Context[0]: Comment: \<!-- to --\> (Escape character \)
            Guidelines: [0x0000001b]
                Classify Differences as Important: false
                    EOL differences are important: N/A
                    Case differences are important: N/A
                    Whitespace differences are important: N/A
                        Treat TABs as Whitespace: N/A
    Character Encoding:
        Automatically detect Unicode BOM: true
        Fallback Handling: Use System Local/Default
    Lines To Omit: [3 patterns]
        LOmit[0]: Each Line Matching: ^[[:blank:]]*$
        LOmit[1]: Each Line Matching: \f
        LOmit[2]: Each Line Matching: \<!--.*--\>
```

The important part is the context start `\<!--`, end `--\>`, escape character `\`

and to realize that the ignored content does not get grayed out.